# Programming the STM32F446RE with a CH340G module

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, uart, programming

I would like to know if it is possible to program an [STM32F446RE](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f446re.pdf) MCU with a CH340G converter. And if it is possible, then how?

Comment: Check out app note AN2606, regarding using the built-in bootloader to flash via UART: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00167594-stm32-microcontroller-system-memory-boot-mode-stmicroelectronics.pdf It should contain pretty much all you need.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, by putting the MCU into factory bootloader mode, and using the specific UART pins that the factory bootloader uses to communicate, for example using ST's own CubeProg application to program the firmware.

Comment: There is still an issue of putting it into bootloader mode (BOOT0+RESET pins). I was thinking about the same thing to program my STM32 (using CH340 or CP2104), but didn't come up with a solution